# Not able to see Ubuntu 14.04 screen via X2GO

Tags: 14.04, x2go

I have been working with Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop edition on a remote server. I am using X2GO client to access it.  Everything is Ok until this morning where I started developing in PyQt4. I set the showFullScreen option to my window in which there is no exit button/menu item. Now I can not see the desktop because of this. Is there a way to resolve this ? I permanently see the blank window covering the whole my screen.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the solution I imagined was quite simple: I run Putty to connect with SSH to the server. Then I listed the processes that were running and I killed the one that caused me the trouble.